# Multithreaded returns different result from single threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a problem with my code which is that the result between multi-threading and single-threaded are different.

I have a function which takes an input image, and rotates in n steps around the center, and does some analysis on that image. To increase the speed of that, I rewrote the function to take as input the start angle, and end angle, and it calculates the values in between.

Prototype is

`void rotateImageConvolution(float* image, int startMin, int startMax)`

Now when I call that function with 0..180, it will return the same result every single time, which works fine.
Since I have a 4 core CPU, I have 3 threads running, going 0..60, 60..120, 120..180, since it goes 
(int i = startMin; i < startMax)

The only write to global memory is

```
            if(convolution_image[i] < convrst)
            {
                WaitForSingleObject( mLock[i],    // handle to mutex
                    INFINITE);  // no time-out interval
                if(convolution_image[i] < convrst)
                {   
                    convolution_image[i] = convrst;
                    r_map_image[i] = (unsigned char)r0;
                    orientation_map_image[i] = (unsigned char)a;
                }
                ReleaseMutex(mLock[i]);
            }
```

where convrst is the result of the convolution, and the convolution_image saves the calculated values. i is the index in the image and goes 0..imagesize
mLock is a block of handles

```
mLock = new HANDLE[imgsize];
for(int i = 0; i < imgsize; ++i)
{
    mLock[i] = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);
}
```

all other memory used is allocated in the function and freed again.
The funny thing is, if I disable the Mutex in the convrst part, I get random results, a lot of different ones. If I enable them, I get one of two results, one being the correct result (the same as the single threaded), and half the time a different one.

I cannot figure out what is happening here, and can't see what's going wrong there.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I'd try using one mutex rather than an array of mutexes first and see if you still get the wrong results.  are all the indexed types in your code just arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your mutex wraps the entire if statement?  Keep in mind that your if statement may be reading in convolution_image[i] while another thread is in the middle of writing it.

The scenario that *may* be tripping you up:

1. Thread 1 just finishes locking the critical section
2. Thread 2 then evaluates the if statement.
3. Thread 2 is then blocked by the mutex
4. Thread 1 unlocks the mutex (and by implication, has calculated convolution_image[i]).
5. Thread 2 then locks the critical section, and then goes and calculates the same convolution_image[i] as thread 1 did in step #4.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what happened, the different threads calculated the same values, thus it was random by which came first.

Comment: Actually, I need to correct myself. I passed a struct to the thread as parameters to call the function, and through a racing condition sometimes parameters were set to the next thread's parameters. Solved this by adding a vector containing all the starting parameters per thread so no mesh-up could happen.